# "commonly known as" or "known commonly as"?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I'm editing a scientific paper, and one of my colleague wrote:

> "...in applications known commonly as 'displays',..."

Personally, I would change it to "commonly known", but I didn't find any formal recommendation for this.

I found those two useful pages, but none of them address this case where an adverb is usedbeside an adjective:

- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position
- https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/AdverbPl.html

Thanks for all bits of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Commonly known as" is grammatically correct.

The adverbs which are placed at end position are known as Adverbs of Manner.

1. It is known as Photosynthesis, commonly.

While, the adverbs that are placed after subject or sub+auxiliary verb, are known as Adverbs of Degree or Intensity.

1. It is commonly known as Photosynthesis.

Thus, it's grammatically incorrect to use any adverb at mid position: known commonly as 'displays'...

But, if you add commas before and after the adverb, it is acceptable, as in this sentence: ...in applications, known, commonly, as 'displays'...

To avoid ambiguity, say: commonly known as 'displays'...

Comment: "Commonly known as" is rhythmically better than "known commonly as" too.

Comment: @rmbianch: Welcome

Comment: @tautophile: you are right.